# C# xml read, show error

Tags: c#, xml

Whats wrong with my code?

```
        XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(@"D:\xml_file.xml");
        textReader.Read();

        // If the node has value

        while (textReader.Read())
        {
            // Move to fist element

            textReader.MoveToElement();
            Console.WriteLine("XmlTextReader Properties Test");
            Console.WriteLine("===================");
            // Read this element's properties and display them on console
            Console.WriteLine("id:" + textReader.id.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("name:" + textReader.name.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("time:" + textReader.time.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine()
```

show erron on: id, name, time

My XML file:

```
<students>
 <student>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Rikko Nora</name>
  <time>2010-03-12</time>
 </student>
 <student>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>Rikko Nora2</name>
  <time>2010-05-15</time>
 </student>
</students>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XmlTextReader does not adapt itself to the shape of the XML that you are reading.  The compilation error that you are getting lies with these lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("id:" + textReader.id.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("name:" + textReader.name.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("time:" + textReader.time.ToString());
```

The XmlTextReader class does not have id, name, and time properties.

Rather, when you use the XmlTextReader, after you move to a node, you will want to use the [ReadContentAs{ContentType} methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader_members.aspx) to read the element content as a particular type instance.

If you are looking to read object representations from XML then you might want to take a look at [XML Serialization in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the new XDocument class to load the XML and than run Linq queries on it.